# What's the best way to debug Amazon S3 errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

So far in my Rails journey, the most frustrating thing by far has been using Amazon S3 for storage. I have had various issues, all without error messages, which is like looking for a needle in a haystack.
How do you debug issues with Amazon S3? For instance at the moment, development shows some images and not all, on my staging server no images are displayed, and production currently shows all images. When I use the browser tools no address for the image is even loaded:

```
<div class="card-img" variant="top" itemprop="image" title="The racing machine driven by joe blogs" style="background: url(< nothing >) no-repeat; background-size: cover">
```

I am looking to deploy some big changes to production, but don't feel confident with missing images.

On a side note, I recently upgraded my rails version and my active storage versions, running the migrations and adding the service column to the blobs table. I'm hoping maybe I made some sort of error in the migration.

Please let me know your experiences with Amazon S3. Thanks!

Comment: You could paste the URL directly in a browser and see what it says. It will normally be `Access Denied`, which then needs further investigation within AWS to figure out why access is not available.

Comment: If it's not inserting URLs at all, this is a problem with your Rails code and/or configuration. Update your question showing your controller and view, and show how you get the supposed URL (I'm assuming you're using some gem; if so, show its configuration).